# Como selecionar valor de um select e manter após submit com PHP

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código que ao selecionar um mês, ele coloca na variável $mes, o valor selecionado:

```
if (isset($_POST['mes']))
{
    $mes = $_POST['mes'];
    echo "$mes";
}

(isset($_POST["mes"])) ? $mes1 = $_POST["mes"] : $mes1=3;
echo '
<form method="post" action="" name="form">  
 <select name="mes" id="mes">
    <option value="1">Janeiro</option>
    <option value="2">Fevereiro</option>
    <option value="3">Março</option>
    <option value="4">Abril</option>
    <option value="5">Maio</option>
    <option value="6">Junho</option>
    <option value="7">Julho</option>
    <option value="8">Agosto</option>
    <option value="9">Setembro</option>
    <option value="10">Outubro</option>
    <option value="11">Novembro</option>
    <option value="12">Dezembro</option>
 </select>
 <input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
';
```

Mas após selecionar e funcionar, o campo select volta para o primeiro valor, no caso Janeiro.

Como faço para, após selecionar e der o ok, o campo select ficar selecionado o valor $mes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução seria colocar os meses em um array e fazer um loop. Após dar o `submit` na página verificar o mês selecionado é igual ao item atual do loop e fazer o `selected`:

```
<?php

$meses = array(1=>'Janeiro', 2=>'Fevereiro', 3=>'Março', 4=>'Abril', 5=>'Maio', 6=>'Junho', 7=>'Julho', 8=>'Agosto', 9=>'Setembro', 10=>'Outubro', 11=>'Novembro', 12=>'Dezembro');

if (isset($_POST['mes']))
{
    $mes = $_POST['mes'];
    echo "$mes";
}
?>
<form method="post" action="" name="form">  
 <select name="mes" id="mes">
    <?php
    foreach($meses as $n=>$m){

        $selected = (isset($_POST['mes']) && $_POST['mes'] == $n) ? 'selected' : '';

        echo '<option value="'.$n.'" '.$selected.'>'.$m.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
 </select>
 <input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: funcionou perfeito! Obrigado!!!

Comment: Aproveitando (esqueci de colocar) no caso de input como ficaria? Tenho um campo input que é o ano <input type="number" id="ano" name="ano" value="2017" style="width:100px;"></input>